# Anyone know why String.matches(regexp) not working on ANSI colored string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to match with regular expression any time the following characters are found: `|<>-` in a string array that has been `split("\n");`  My code is as follows:

```
String[] s_array = perged.split("\n");

    for (String s_array1 : s_array) {

        if (s_array1.matches("(.*)[|><-](.*)")) {

            System.out.println("~m~" + s_array1);

        } else {

           System.out.print("~false~");

           System.out.println(s_array1);
        }
    }
```

one of the many strings trying to be matched is:

```
 <---------^--------->
 | HH#...........### |  Exits
```

These should match and if I just copy paste the strings they will test true with my regexp.  However the actual strings being parsed have `\u001B` characters for ANSI color codes in them.  I believe these are causing the issues.  So instead of `(.*)` I tried `(\\D*)` and it still didn't work thinking maybe the `'.'` was not accepting the \u001B characters.

```
  if (s_array1.matches("(\\D*)[|><-](\\D*)")) {
```

The actual strings being parsed look like this:

```
[37;1m<[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m^[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m>[0m[34;1m[0m\u000D\u000A
 [34;1m| [0m[0m[35mHH[0m[0m[37m#[0m[0m[33m..........[0m[1;32mp[0m[0m[37m###[0m[34;1m |[0m  Exits:  \u000D\u000A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not committed to using matches for this I just didn't want to do

```
 if(s_array1.contains("<") || s_array1.contains(">") ....
```

I'd prefer a more advanced way if one exists for future problems of the same type.

**EDIT**

I have now tried a temp string to remove escapes it's still evaluating as `false`:

```
String[] s_array = perged.split("\n");

    for (String s_array1 : s_array) {

        String temp=s_array1.replaceAll("\u001B", "");
        System.out.println(temp);
        if (temp.matches("(.*)[|><-](.*)")) {

            System.out.println("~m~" + s_array1);

        } else {

           System.out.print("~false~");

           System.out.println(s_array1);

        }

    }
```

A simple test is evaluating as `true` so I'm not sure if there is a character or byte that can force the expression to be `false`:

```
String s="[37;1m<[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m^[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m>[0m[34;1m[0m  Loc:    [36mDortlewall (Crystite plaza)                    [m";
    if(s.matches("(.*)[|><-](.*)")){
        System.out.println("It was true yay!!");
    }else
    System.out.println("It was false BOOO:");
```

Comment: The utf-16 representation for the literal '\' character is `\u001B`. After the parser decodes `\u001B` it puts a literal escape into the now in-memory string. I don't see your point. If the in-memory string contains an escape, then a regex containing metachar `.` dot will match it.

Comment: It's evaluating as false I don't know why.  I updated with my second attempt at circumventing the string however it will not evaluate to true with the String.matches().

Comment: Try using the _Dot-All_ modifier flag ( or substitute `[\S\s]` for the dot). Could be the characters in the class are on a different line in the string.

Comment: `replaceAll("\u001B")` probably better passed to engine as `replaceAll("\\u001B")` or `replaceAll("\\\\")` because in memory, the engine must see `\u001B` or `\\ `, in code, the parser should see `"\\\\"`

Comment: Any chance you could post a sample of your input that has the ANSI control characters? (As a file on Dropbox or something; there's probably no way to reliably incorporate it as text in your question. E.g. that last test with a String literal is not going to have the actual control characters in it.)

Comment: [\S\s] worked thank you sln!!!  Changed the replaceAll("\\u001B") didn't help but if it's the right way to do it I'll keep it changed.  Any ideas why the Ss worked and not the .?

Comment: And just a sanity check... is your input in DOS mode? (With "\r\n" line terminators.) In that case, your `split("\n")` might leave `\r` characters in the strings, which `.` may not match. The DOTALL modifier that @sln suggests would take care of that too.

Comment: That sounds consistent with DOS mode input. The `.` wouldn't match the leftover `\r` by default, but `[\S\s]` would.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Yeah it's a telnet connection so I'm not sure I tried showing all the character codes left over while receiving the stream which is another question I have but got down voted and unanswered so I wasn't able to learn all that was being streamed over the pipe.  Not all lines come with \r\n terminators I know that though.  I'll have to find the DOTALL modifier but sln [\\S\\s] works great

Comment: @AndrewJanke yeah it had the \r \u000D I put it in the String above before the \n \u000A.  Didn't realize it was reading that

Answer (score 0):

I changed the if condition to use `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

```
    String perged = "[37;1m<[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m^[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m>[0m[34;1m[0m  Loc:    [36mDortlewall (Crystite plaza)                    [m";
    String[] s_array = perged.split("\n");

    for (String s_array1 : s_array) {

        if (Pattern.matches("(.*)[|><-](.*)" , s_array1)) {

            System.out.println("~m~" + s_array1);

        } else {

           System.out.print("~false~");

           System.out.println(s_array1);
        }
    }


}
```

This prints

`~m~[37;1m<[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m^[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m>[0m[34;1m[0m  Loc:    [36mDortlewall (Crystite plaza)                    [m`

If there happen to be a `\n` in perged before `Loc:`, the result would be :

`~m~[37;1m<[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m^[0m[34;1m---------[0m[37;1m>[0m[34;1m[0m

~false~Loc:    [36mDortlewall (Crystite plaza)`